# Error occurs when no checkbox is checked (in PHP)

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a php code where data from my database are fetched in an array with checkbox corresponding each data . I already have the codes enabling updates to my table (for each data checked):

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$user=$_SESSION['username'];
$updated = FALSE;
$submit=FALSE;
if(count($_POST) > 0){

$library = $_POST['library'];
array_map('intval',$library);
$library = implode(',',$library);
mysql_query("UPDATE ES_Students SET library=0") or trigger_error(mysql_error

(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_query("UPDATE ES_Students SET library=1 WHERE StudentNO IN ($library)") or        trigger_error

(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$submit=TRUE;
$updated=TRUE;
}
?>
```

My problem is, whenever no checkbox is checked, an error will occur that the library index is undefined and all. I know it's got something to do with the $count($_POST)>0 but I don't actually know how to fix this. I tried putting an else-clause to redirect it to another page but it will result to same error. Can anyone tell me what to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `isset` around your post. [PHP link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if( isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
  ....
```

If any data is sent at all, even a blank form, `isset($_POST)` will return true, but with a `count($_POST)` of 0. So, you could also test for the exact items of the array you're looking for to be sure it is infact in the `$_POST` :

```
if( isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['library'])){
 ....
```

Comment: @Sang You're welcome. If this answer solves your question, do be sure to come back and hit the checkmark to 'accept' it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should check if $_POST['library'] contains any items, because if it's empty, then the implode function returns an empty string and your query looks like ... IN () which is not valid sql syntax.